# Alternatives to Seaborn Lineplot limit for multiple line types?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, seaborn, line-plot

I have some longitudinal test data and I wanted to examine the overall trend for this data. My data is set up like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_data = pd.read_csv('./Files Used to Generate Graphs/test_data.csv',header = 0)
test_data
```

[image]

The way I want to plot this data is to have each donor have his/her own longitudinal data line, but color each line based on the gender of the donor like this:

```
test_plt = sns.lineplot(x = 'Timepoint',y = 'Prevalence',
                   hue = 'Gender',
                   data = test_data,
                   style = 'Donor',
                   palette = dict(Male = 'red',
                                 Female = 'blue'))

for line in test_plt.lines:
    line.set_linestyle("-")
ax = plt.gca()
legend = ax.legend()
legend.set_visible(False)
plt.figure()
```

[image]

However, it seems that seaborn's lineplot's *style* argument is capped at 6 types. If I try to add another donor to my data and plot it, I get this:

```
append_df = pd.DataFrame(index = [12,13],
                    columns = ['Donor','Timepoint','Gender','Prevalence'])
append_df['Donor'] = 7
append_df['Gender'] = 'Female'
append_df.loc[12,'Timepoint'] = 1945
append_df.loc[13,'Timepoint'] = 1948
append_df.loc[12,'Prevalence'] = 18
append_df.loc[13,'Prevalence'] = 36
test_data = test_data.append(append_df)
test_data
```

[image]

```
test_plt = sns.lineplot(x = 'Timepoint',y = 'Prevalence',
                   hue = 'Gender',
                   data = test_data,
                   style = 'Donor',
                   palette = dict(Male = 'red',
                                 Female = 'blue'))

for line in test_plt.lines:
    line.set_linestyle("-")
ax = plt.gca()
legend = ax.legend()
legend.set_visible(False)
plt.figure()
```

[image]

So is there a way to bypass this limit on *lineplot* or do I have to go through Matplotlib for this? If the latter, how would the Matplotlib code look like?

On a separate note, is there a way to generate the legend on the seaborn plot that shows the gender of each donor and not each specific donor?

Comment: What would be the purpose of `style` when you set them all to `"-"` afterwards anyways?

Comment: If I don't use style, each donor gets clumped together based on their gender. Instead of 6-7 lines, one for each donor, you would have 2 lines: one for female and one for male. This masks the variation between donor to donor

Comment: So using `style` is just a workaround for a completely different problem. Better ask for the original problem then.